# Django local variable referenced before assignment error when updating via modelformset

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, modelform

I have this view to edit 3 ModelForms (2 via ModelFormSet):

```
@login_required
def reviserdossier(request, pk):
    DocumentFormSet = modelformset_factory(DocumentdeBase, form=DocumentdebaseForm, extra=5)
    PhotoAvantFormSet = modelformset_factory(PhotoAvant, form=PhotoAvantForm, extra=5)
    instance_dossier = Dossier.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dossierForm = DossierForm(request.POST, instance=instance_dossier)
        formset = DocumentFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=DocumentdeBase.objects.none())
        formset2 = PhotoAvantFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=PhotoAvant.objects.none())
        if dossierForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid() and formset2.is_valid():
            if instance_dossier.rejection_count == 1:
                dossier_form = dossierForm.save(commit=False)
                dossier_form.status_admin = 'Validation OR Requise'
                dossier_form.status_prestataire = "En Attente d'ordre de réparation"
                dossier_form.rejection_count = 0
                dossier_form.save()
            elif instance_dossier.rejection_count == 2:
                dossier_form = dossierForm.save(commit=False)
                dossier_form.status_admin = 'Dossier à clôturer'
                dossier_form.status_prestataire = "En attente de clôture"
                dossier_form.rejection_count = 0
                dossier_form.save()

            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form:
                    image = form['documentdebase_image']
                    photo = DocumentdeBase(dossier=dossier_form, documentdebase_image=image)
                    photo.save()
            for form2 in formset2.cleaned_data:
                #this helps to not crash if the user   
                #do not upload all the photos
                if form2:
                    image2 = form2['photoavant_image']
                    photo2 = PhotoAvant(dossier=dossier_form, photoavant_image=image2)
                    photo2.save()
            #messages.success(request, "Dossier révisé!")
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            print(dossierForm.errors, formset.errors, formset2.errors)
    else:
        dossierForm = DossierForm(instance=instance_dossier)
        formset = DocumentFormSet(queryset=DocumentdeBase.objects.none())
        formset2 = PhotoAvantFormSet(queryset=PhotoAvant.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'dashboard/reviser_dossier.html',
                  {'dossierForm': dossierForm, 'formset': formset, 'formset2': formset2, 'dossier': instance_dossier})
```

This is my forms.py:

```
class DossierForm(forms.ModelForm):
    mat_id = forms.CharField(max_length=7, label="N°")
    mattypes = (
        ('A - أ', 'A - أ'),
        ('B - ب', 'B - ب'),
        ('D - د', 'D - د'),
        ('H - ه', 'H - ه'),
        ('O - و', 'O - و'),
        ('M - المغرب', 'M - المغرب'),
        ('P - ش', 'P - ش'),
        ('J - ج', 'J - ج'),
        ('FAR - ق م م', 'FAR - ق م م'),
        ('FA - ق س', 'FA - ق س'),
        ('PC - و م', 'PC - و م'),
        ('CD - ه د', 'CD - ه د'),
        ('CI - ت د', 'CI - ت د'),
        ('CC - ت د', 'CC - ت د'),
        ('WW', 'WW'),
        ('W18', 'W18'),
        ('96', '96'),
        ('97', '97'),
        ('98', '98'),
        ('99', '99'),
    )
    mat_symbol = forms.CharField(label='Symbole', widget=forms.Select(choices=mattypes))
    mat_ville = forms.CharField(max_length=2, label='Ville')
    assurance = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Assurance.objects.all())
    ville = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=City.objects.all())
    intermediaire = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Intermediaire.objects.all())
    marque = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Marque.objects.all())
    model = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Model.objects.all())
    client_name = forms.CharField(max_length=70)
    num_police = forms.IntegerField()
    glace_type = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=GlassType.objects.all())
    glace = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Glass.objects.all())
    joint = forms.BooleanField(initial=False, required=False)
    OV = ( # Options Vitre
        ('AD', 'AD'),
        ('SD', 'SD'),
        ('T', 'T'),
        ('ST', 'ST'),
    )

    option_vitre = forms.CharField(label='Option vitre', widget=forms.Select(choices=OV))
    valeur_assuree = forms.IntegerField(label='Valeur assurée')
    num_sinistre = forms.IntegerField(label='N° sinistre')
    date_sinistre = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(months=MONTHS), label='Date sinistre')
    date_effet = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(months=MONTHS), label='Date effet')
    date_echeance = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget(months=MONTHS), label='Date échéance')
    franchise_contractuelle = forms.IntegerField(label='Franchise contractuelle')
    franchise_a_recuperer = forms.IntegerField(label='Franchise à récupérer')
    tva_a_recuperer = forms.IntegerField(label='TVA à récupérer')
    commentaire = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, label='Commentaire')


    class Meta:
        model = Dossier
        fields = ('mat_id', 'mat_symbol', 'mat_ville', 'assurance', 'ville',
        'intermediaire', 'marque', 'model', 'client_name', 'num_police',
        'glace_type', 'glace', 'joint', 'option_vitre', 'valeur_assuree',
        'num_sinistre', 'date_sinistre', 'date_effet', 'date_echeance',
        'franchise_contractuelle', 'franchise_a_recuperer', 'tva_a_recuperer',
        'commentaire')

class DocumentdebaseForm(forms.ModelForm):
    documentdebase_image = forms.ImageField(label='')

    class Meta:
        model = DocumentdeBase
        fields = ('documentdebase_image',)

class PhotoAvantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    photoavant_image = forms.ImageField(label='')

    class Meta:
        model = PhotoAvant
        fields = ('photoavant_image',)
```

When I run the view, I find this error:

```
Exception Type:     UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:    local variable 'dossier_form' referenced before assignment
```

Here is the scenario: I want to edit 3 forms in the same view/template. I created a similar view for creating new models and it works just fine (very similar view, only this time I add the pk of the existing model to modify, and add it in the GET method scenario). 
What seems to be the problem?

Comment: if `instance_dossier.rejection_count` is neither 1 or 2 then `dossier_form` is never defined, you are then referencing `dossier_form` when you loop over the formsets

Comment: The rejection count is 2, I double check it in the admin interface. And because of how the rejection count algorithm is made, it will never ever equal anything except these 2 numbers.

Comment: Solved! I just changed it to 2 if statements instead of if else. I don't know why but it's working now.